# How to make ion-range a required field inside a form

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

To get user ratings I am using a ion-range component inside a form. Though it is a required field system allow to save reviews without set the rating value.

```
<ion-content>
<form #Form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()" >   
    <ion-item>
      <ion-range min="0" max="100" pin="true" [(ngModel)]="rating" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
        <ion-icon range-left name="sad"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon range-right name="happy"></ion-icon>
      </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button [disabled]="!Form.form.valid" ion-button full color="secondary" >Save</button>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `required` attribute is not part of the [Range component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/), so it won't work in that way.

What you can do, is to add another condition to the `disabled` attribute of the button, like this

```
<button ion-button [disabled]="!Form.form.valid || rating === 0" ion-button full color="secondary" >Save</button>
```

This way the button will still be disabled if the `rating` property is equal to 0.